# Indy9のTIdTCPConnection.ReadBufferと同等の機能はありますか？

Tags: delphi

Indy9で書かれたコードの

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
     BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
----------(中略)---------------------------------------

AThread->Connection->ReadBuffer((BYTE *)&Pkt,sizeof(BKUK_PACKET));

----------(中略)---------------------------------------
}
```

ReadBufferという名前の機能はIndy10では見当たらないのですが、同等の機能はありますでしょうか？

コードではPktのポインターのメモリ位置に受信したBKUK_PACKETのデータ内容を移動させていると思われます。

BKUK_PACKET(仮名)というのはこのような感じの1200バイト程度のデータ内容です。

```
typedef struct _BKUK_PACKET_
{
    BYTE head[4];
    WORD PayLoad;
    WORD Length;
    BYTE Data[1200];
    WORD Ver;
    BYTE tail[2];
}BKUK_PACKET;
```

以前Indyを使った時に、データ受信などで

```
AnsiString rcvdStr;


    rcvdStr = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding(932));
```

このような感じの”ReadLn()”データを受信したことはあるのですが、今回の場合でもReadLn()は使用できますでしょうか？

**（途中経過）**

```
Context->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes((BYTE *)&Pkt,sizeof(BKUK_PACKET))
```

ReadBytesという機能を見つけて、上記のようにプログラムしてみたのですが、次のようなエラーが出ます。

> [bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(530): non-const lvalue reference to type 'Idglobal::TIdBytes' (aka 'DynamicArray') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'BYTE *' (aka 'unsigned char *')
>     IdIOHandler.hpp(235): passing argument to parameter 'VBuffer' here

このようなエラーが出てくるのですが、対策方法などありますでしょうか？

Comment: 英語版にて解決済みのようです - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59125361

Comment: マルチポストはルールで禁止されているわけではありませんが、マナーとしての考え方はメタの投稿も参考にしてください。 - [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

お世話になっております。
こちらのサイトで、とりあえず解決できましたので報告させて頂きます。

Answer: Is there an indy9 function called ReadBuffer in Indy10? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59126191/12281072?stw=2

Comment: リンクではなく、回答の中身を共有してもらえると良いQAになります。